# Angular Modal Scope Value Not Setting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap UI and using a Modal. I have a variable in my main controller that is instantiated on controller load.

```
$scope.links = {
            imagesa: ""
        };
```

This variable does not get set with the value 'wept' after I close the modal.

Any ideas what the issue is here?

Here is the function to open the Modal dialog

```
    $scope.instagramModal = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'instagramModal.html',
            controller: 'InstagramModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $sails.get("/instagram/self").success(function (response) {

                        return response.data;

                    }).error(function (response) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.links.imagesa = 'Wept';

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
```

This is the modalDialog controller

```
.controller('InstagramModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance,items) {

        $scope.instapics = JSON.parse(items.data);

        $scope.selectIG = function(index) {
         $modalInstance.close($scope.instapics.data[index]);
        }

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It clearly states: "scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided scope). Defaults to $rootScope". Either pass your scope to `$modal.open`, or use `$close(result)`.

Comment: $scope.links.imagesa = "wept" is not set and this gets set $scope.testthisset = "set". Is there an issue with how i assign the value to the object? I have the object initialised on the main controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing the modal?

You have to close the modal with `.close()` and not `dismiss()`

```
$modalInstance.close();
```

Comment: The value is being returned from the modal controller. Its when its in the modalInstance.result.then function that main variable in global scope is not set. I updated the question to show the modal code

Answer (score 0):

Your `items` object is returning a `$promise` object and not the `data` object as you are expecting.

I wouldn't resolve an injection dependency like that. I'd probably wrap the call to `$sails` into a service. However, if you want to do that way, trying using the `success` function inside your modal controller.

```
resolve: {
    items: function () {
        return $sails.get("/instagram/self");
}
```

//on your modal controller

```
.controller('InstagramModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    items.then(function (response) {
        $scope.instapics = JSON.parse(response.data);
    })
});
```